# Constructors features in Lombok

Tags: java, spring, lombok

If I have a class with three instance variables and one instance final variable.

Will I be restricted from creating the instance of that class using the no-argument constructor?

```
public @Data class Employee {

    private Integer empId;

    private String empName;

    private Country country;

    private final Integer var;

}
```

When tried to compile the following line

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

Then, I got this error

> requires argument to match Employee(Integer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will restrict the use of no-args constructor, unless you initialize the final variable. If you initialize the final variable, it will allow to create the instance of that class using default no-argument constructor. But no setter will be generated to that final variable, however, getter will be generated.
Even if we use, `@NoArgsConstructor`, it will throw compiler error stating,
`final variable may not be initialized`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Integer var` is final. You can set a final variable only in a constructor or in an initializer.

So in this case, you can't do with constructor using lombok, you need to init your final variable first

```
private final Integer var = someValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `var` is final. Remove the final, to allow the `var` reference to be re-assignable.

Comment: Final fields can be mutable

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer**

**yes**, you are restricted from creating an instance of that class using a no-argument constructor.

**The long answer**

From the [documentation for `@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data):

> @Data is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of
>   @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter / @Setter and
>   **@RequiredArgsConstructor** together

[`@RequiredArgsConstructor` is](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor):

> @RequiredArgsConstructor generates a constructor with 1 parameter for
>   each field that requires special handling. **All non-initialized final
>   fields get a parameter**, as well as any fields that are marked as
>   @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared.

As you should know, Java does not generate a default no-argument constructor if you have already defined your own constructor - and by using Lombok's `@Data` annotation, you have.

You could *explicitly* add Lombok's `@NoArgsConstructor`, however:

> @NoArgsConstructor will generate a constructor with no parameters. **If
>   this is not possible (because of final fields), a compiler error will
>   result instead**